# Objects being deformed in render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I am doing a close up for a detail of my scene, but when i get the render, some objects of my scene get distorted to get into the render, and I don't want those objects to appear in my render. And the material or the floor got deformed too. What can I do?

This is the view that I want ...

[image: before]

But this is what I get, As you can see the Table and the towel warmer get distorted to get into the scene.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I suggest adding images to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Maybe glass shader is a culprit? And check if there are any unwanted shapekeyes or difference between modifier's render/viewport settings.

Comment: @SergeL Yes! It was the material of the glass door. I would had never thought that, thank you!!!

Comment: In the outliner, you can set objects to be disabled in viewport and separately disabled in render. Have a look at the "filter" button.